# Laravel - same custom error message for multiple fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Im using a form request for validation and want to customize my errors. since I have a lot of fields to validate,I want to know if it is possible to use the same error message for multiple fields that have the same validation rule.

My actual form request looks like :

```
class CreateServerRequest extends Request
{
     public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'srv_prefix' => 'required|regex:/^[A-Z][-_A-Z0-9]*$/',
        //20 more to go...

    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'srv_prefix.required' => 'required.',
        'srv_prefix.regex' => 'nope, bad format.'
    ];
}
}
```

I dont like the idea of adding as many lines of errors as fields (some fields may have 2 validation rules..) is there any way to tell laravel `if validation rule = required then show this type of error` regardless of the field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use just the validation name as the key for the message array, if you want all messages for that particular validation to be the same:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'required' => 'The field :attribute is required.',
        'regex'    => 'nope, bad format.'
    ];
}
```

You can use `:attribute` as a placeholder that will be replaced with the field name, if you need that to be part of the error message. The documentation for this is in the [Validation Custom Error Messages](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-error-messages) section, not in the [Form Request Validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation) one.

Comment: thanks for your help. A small detail that should not be forgotten : each field should have a holder to display the error in it : `{!! $errors->first('srv_preifx','<span class="help-block">:message</span>')!!}`